# Cómo imprimir estos dos valores en un ciclo For de JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Disculpen, cómo se puede hacer para que este ciclo for me imprima valor 1 con el contador 18, valor 2 con el contador 19, valor 3 con el contador 20 y asi sucesivamente hasta que valor sea igual a 16 y contador sea igual a 33.

Intenté con esto pero me imprime 256 veces, es decir me recorre 16 veces el contador por cada valor. Adjunto el codigo

```
for (contador3 = 1 ; contador3 <=16; contador3++){
            var opcion = '#opcionesA' + String(contador3); 
            var valor = $(opcion).combobox('getValue');  


            for (contador4 = 18; contador4 <= 33; contador4++){
                console.log("DESEO QUE ME IMPRIMA EL VALOR: ", valor) + console.log("EN CONJUNTO CON EL CONTADOR: ",contador4);

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si solo vas a mostrar un número, no necesitas un ciclo, sino una simple suma:

```js
for (contador3 = 1 ; contador3 <=16; contador3++){
    let opcion = '#opcionesA' + String(contador3); 
    // let valor = $(opcion).combobox('getValue');
    let valor = 'Valor obtenido de un select';

    // No necesitas un ciclo, solo sumar 17 para obtener el valor deseado
    let contador4 = contador3 + 17;
    console.log("DESEO QUE ME IMPRIMA EL VALOR: ", valor) + console.log("EN CONJUNTO CON EL CONTADOR: ",contador4);
}
```

**Nota:** Comenté la declaración original de `valor` y agregué otra, para poder probar; en tu proyecto, descomenta esa línea y elimina la siguiente.

Comment: gracias, pero si necesito mostrar los 16 numero

Comment: @EduardoLucero, el ciclo que se elimina es el interno. Ejecuta el fragmento de código para comprobar que se muestran los 16 números.

Comment: GRACIAS @Triby me funciono

Comment: @EduardoLucero si resolvió tu pregunta, recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada, usando el tick junto a los votos de la respuesta (hazle clic)